# Using orderBy for custom sorting in Spring Boot

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, sql-order-by

I'm unable to figure out the Spring query for my SQL query

```
SELECT person_name, role FROM persons
GROUP BY person_name, role
ORDER BY ROLE = 'viewer',
     ROLE = 'participant',
     ROLE = 'collaborator',
     ROLE = 'lead';
```

I tried

```
select(field("person_name"), field("role"))
 .from(table("person")
 .groupBy(field("person_name"), field("role"))
 .orderBy((field("role").equals("viewer")).and(field("role").equals("participant")).and(
               field("role").equals("collaborator")).and(field("role").equals("lead")));
```

but no luck.

If I do orderBy(role) then I'm getting ascending order result like
collaborator > lead > participant > viewer

But I'm expecting lead > collaborator > participant > viewer

Comment: Why the GROUP BY? Do you simply want SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: @jarlh Earlier, I thought of having them in groups thats why GROUP BY. And now thinking of only ORDER BY would do the job. 
DISTINCT returns only unique records.